# Select columns with name matching str with wildcard for t-test (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have

```
         Apple f2 m  Apple f2 t  Apple f3 m   Apple f3 t
0                 3           4           5            3
1                 12          7           4            7  
2                 5           9           7            5
3                 3           3           4            8
4                 7           1           2            6
```

I would like to select columns with str = 'Apple f* m' to do a t-test against columns with str = 'Apple f* t'

I have tried

```
ttest_ind(df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Apple R* m')], df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Apple R* t')]
```

However, it doesn't recognise my wildcard has a wildcard.

Thank you if you an help me solve or guide me for this problem.

Comment: I don't think you can use a wildcard there. Try a regular expression.

Comment: actually...I just tried df.columns.str.contains('Apple.*m') and worked perfectly. Thanks for answering !

Comment: Yep I was going to say add a dot. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197394/what-does-do-in-regex

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For future reference. The [pandas.Series.str.contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) has the param regex set to True by default which means we can use Regex expressions.

To find 0 or more of any character we can simply use this (ref. Alan Moore)

> .* just means "0 or more of any character"
>
> It's broken down into two parts:
>
> . - a "dot" indicates any character
>   * - means "0 or more instances of the preceding regex token"

Here is a link to regex101 where you can test regex expressions:

https://regex101.com/r/QNjkch/1

And finally we can simplify your code, consider this simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a1a","a2a","a1b"])

mask = df.columns.str.contains('a.*a')

df.loc[:,mask] # selects mask
df.loc[:,~mask] # selects inverted (by using ~) mask
```

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to Anton vBR's answer, this is how you'd do it, using `str.contains`.

```
i = df.columns.str.contains(r'Apple\s+f\d+\s+m')
j = df.columns.str.contains(r'Apple\s+f\d+\s+t')

df.iloc[:, i]
   Apple f2 m  Apple f3 m
0           3           5
1          12           4
2           5           7
3           3           4
4           7           2

df.iloc[:, j]
   Apple f2 t  Apple f3 t
0           4           3
1           7           7
2           9           5
3           3           8
4           1           6
```

---

**Regex Details**

```
Apple     # "Apple"
\s+       # 1 or more spaces
f         # "f"
\d+       # 1 or more digits
\s+       # 1 or more spaces
m         # "m"
```