# REGEX to get all email addresses from forwarded gmail

Tags: regex

I need to get all email addresses from TO, From and cc(Separately) from forwarded email body.
Is this possible with regex?

I am new to regex so don't understand it completely. Can someone help me build this logic?

Comment: This isn't the place to ask someone to solve your problem from scratch. Q's go down a lot better if you do some reading first and ask about a specific point that you're stuck on. Example input and output text is also useful

Answer (score 1):

### REGEX LOGIC

You could use `[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+` from [regex extract email from strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42407785/regex-extract-email-from-and) then also add an additional part to it which would allow you to identify CC / To / From separately.

> The pattern is 1 or more occurrences of:
>
> ```
> a-z: any lowercase letter
> A-Z: any uppercase letter
> 0-9: any digit
> -_.: a hyphen, an underscore or a dot
> ```

So something like this could work `CC:.*[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+`. Here I added in `CC:.*` in the front which makes it so the regex will only grab the line that has `CC` in it.

> .* just means "0 or more of any character"
>
> It's broken down into two parts:
>
> ```
> . - a "dot" indicates any character
> * - means "0 or more instances of the preceding regex token"
> ```

From: [What does .* do in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21197394/what-does-do-in-regex)

---

## EXAMPLE USE

`CC:.*[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+` will grab the line that has a `CC:` in the front of it.
[image: Example of CC:.*[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+]

You would then do a secondary regex of just `[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+` with out the `CC:` identifier to extract each email from the line separately.
[image: Example of [a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+]

Then just do this for each of the three lines you want to capture (to and from).

The regex used is this one: https://regex101.com/r/KIbf1T/1